# What's the imperial equivalent to "royalty" in the sense of "members of the imperial family"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Saying "members of the imperial family of Japan" is quite a mouthful, so I'd like something more succinct, like how you say "British royalty". "Imperiality" seems nice, but the only dictionary that lists "imperial person" is [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/imperiality), so I'm not quite sure whether it could be easily understood as "members of the imperial family". Also the definition "imperial person" listed by Lexico is kind of vague, I'm not sure if it means "a member of the imperial family", or "an imperialist" which could be bad.

Sample sentence:

> The Okimi no Tsukasa is a government department in charge of attending to members of the imperial family.

Comment: Imperial family is a quite widespread expression: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22imperial%20family%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1997,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: The full OED has as definition 2 for **imperiality**  (Chiefly in plural) *An imperial person. (Cf. **royalty** noun). In a quotation from 1839   as a mass noun: **imperial persons collectively.*** It's just not a common usage. As with ***royalists***, mere "supporters" of the system would be ***imperialists***, not ***imperiality***.

Comment: [Self and Other in Esteemed Status: The Changing Culture of the Japanese Royalty from Showa to Heisei](https://www.jstor.org/stable/133158)

Comment: Aren't members of the imperial family just *the imperial family*?

Comment: Saying "members of the Japanese imperiality" arguably sounds worse. // Wiktionary gives two existing senses of 'imperiality' not parallel to the default sense of 'royalty' (the Royals) but then lists 'royalty' as a 'synonym'.

Comment: @YosefBaskin by that logic we would never say "members of" anything. Besides I think "royalty" could be understood as "members other than the queen" for example, so specific words certainly offer more nuance. Being "treated like royalty is one thing", being "treated like the queen" is another.

Comment: Another option is to use the name of the dynasty, e.g. one Romanov, several Romanovs, although this is less usual with the Japanese royal family (house of Yamato): Wikipedia's article [Imperial House of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_House_of_Japan) repeatedly uses the phrase "members of the Imperial Family", suggesting there is nothing more succinct.

Comment: @StuartF Are you sure this is applicable to this particular family? "One Romanov" implies that Romanov is used like a family name, and there have been dynasties with true family names, but unfortunately Japan's is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

> something more succinct

**Japanese royalty.**

From Google Books (snippet view)

> Mutual Perceptions and Images in Japanese-German Relations, 2017, PAGE 176
> *In addition, Japanese royalty, military personnel, diplomats, and statesmen were occasionally mentioned by name*

> The Japanese toso-kinko Schools - Page 127, Markus Sesko · 2012 *The „Sōken-kishō“ lists him as chūnagon (中納言) and that he held the third court rank, but records on Japanese royalty list Moroka as gon-chūnagon (権中納言)*

> Jack’S Japonica - Page 39 Jack Nakamoto · 2011 *Bowing is a Japanese custom whether it be for greeting, thanking, leave-taking, or apologizing, but there is a special bow for the Japanese royalty.*

Comment: I guess for good measure one could say *Japanese imperial royalty.*

Comment: @aparente001 That seems redundant, as there is no other type of Japanese royalty.

Comment: @Barmar - Okay, how about *imperial royalty*?